# Why do I need to use "self" to reference the class variable in a class method?

Tags: python

```
class Channel(object)
  channel_mapping = {
    'a': 001,
    'b': 002,
    'c': 003
  }

  def __init__(self):
    ...

  def process(self, input):
    channels = input.split(',')
    for channel in channels:
       if channel in self.channel_mapping:
          channel = self.channel_mapping[channel]
          break
     ...
```

I defined `channel_mapping` as class variable, and why do I need to use `self` to refer to it? I thought I should just use `channel_mapping` or `cls.channel_mapping` in the `process()` function.

Also, to define `channel_mapping` as a class variable like this, or define it as an instance variable in the initializer, is there any thread safety concern in either case?

Comment: You can use `self.channel_mapping` or `Channel.channel_mapping` in the case where `channel_mapping` is read-only. This then also means it should be thread-safe.

Comment: @quamrana, so my channel_mapping is read-only right? No write to it after its initial population.

Comment: Classes do not create a new scope. `channel_mapping` is not a global variable; it is a class attribute, and thus is only accessible via the class (or an instance of the class).

Comment: `channel_mapping` only exists after the `dict` it references is created and populated. You also have to ensure that you don't ever write to it to make it read-only. It is still read-only by coincidence.

Comment: [this might help](https://www.programiz.com/article/python-self-why)

Comment: The same reason you need to write `self.process(...)` to call a method; the method, too, is declared on the class rather than the instance, but class declarations can't be referred to by simple names from within methods.

Comment: Class attributes like `channel_mapping` are not "read-only" per se, it all depends on what type of object is involved. In this case it's a dictionary, which are mutable, so its value (contents) _can_ be changed by any of the class methods. When a variable shouldn't be change, its name if often made `ALL_UPPERCASE` to indicate this (although that won't prevent it from being done).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I defined 'channel_mapping' as class variable, and why do I need to
> use 'self' to refer to it?

You can refer class variable via `self` (if you ensure it's read-only) and `cls` inside the class and it's methods and via classes object or instances from outside of the class.

What is the difference between using `cls` and `self`? `cls` is being used in classmethods since they doesn't require initialization and so instance of the object, and `self` is used inside the methods which do require instances of the object.

> I thought I should just use
> 'channel_mapping'

Scopes inside python doesn't work as in C# for example, where you can call class variable by just writing it's name omitting `this` where it's redundant. In Python you **have to** use `self` to refer to the instance's variable. Same goes to the class variables but with `cls` (or `self`) instead.

If you are referencing `channel_mapping` you are just referencing a variable from the current or a global scopes whether it exists or not and not from the class or it's instance.

> or cls.channel_mapping in the 'process' function?

From the class methods you would want for sure to use `cls.channel_mapping` since `cls` represents class object. But from the instance's methods, where instead of `cls` you have `self` you can refer to the class variable using `self.__class__.channel_mapping`. What it does is simply returning instance's class which is equal to `cls`, and calls class variable `channel_mapping` afterwards.

`self.channel_mapping` though would return the same result but just because in your code there are no instance attribute called `channel_mapping` and so python can resolve your reference to the class variable. But if there would be `channel_mapping` variable inside the instance it won't be any longer related to the original class variables, so in that case you would want to keep `channel_mapping` read-only.

Summarise, to refer class variable from the class method you would want to just use a `cls` and to refer class variable from the instance method you better use `self.__class__.var` construction instead of `self.var` one.

> Also, to define 'channel_mapping' as a class variable like this, or define it as an instance variable in the initializer, is there any thread safety concern in either case?

There are situations when you want to change variables in all instances simultaneously, and that's when class variables comes in handy, you won't need to update every responsible instance variable in every instance, you will just update class variable and that's it.

But speaking of thread safety I'm not really sure will it be simultaneously updated in every thread or not, but `self.__class__` will return updated version of a class a soon as it will be updated, so `self.__class__` variables will be up to date every time you call it minimizing period within which different threads will use different values of the same variable.

Going up with the initialized variable though, will take longer to update if there are more than one instance so i **would** consider it less threadsafe.

Comment: In my code there is no update to the channel_mapping dict by any method, so it should be thread safe. Right?

Comment: @marlon for sure, if you have no any intentions to somehow change channel_mapping (im talking both of the class one and the instance variable since in your case they are the same) from inside or outside, then yeah, it will be threadsafe since there are no any possible lag in updating variables as you won't update them at all.