# How to use a variable in another function without making it global?

Tags: python, variables

(Py file) So, I am trying to make two commands for a discord bot and in 1 command it makes 3 variables. but I need to use those in another command. it's a Pokémon bot and in the first command it makes 3 random variables
[code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqfNt.png) [part2 of code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg6iU.png)

and so, I need those starter variables in another command called pick_(pokemon name)

```
 await ctx.channel.send (f'Your Starters are... {starterchoice1}, {starterchoice2} and {starterchoice3}. type .pick_The pokemons name to pick')
```

and I need the variables in this code, so it knows what starters he has to pick from.
I have tried storing the variable value in a JSON file, but I knew there has to be an easier and better way.

Comment: could you return the values from the first function directly into the second?

Comment: also I recommend replacing the first part with a dictionary

Comment: sorry I am kind of new to coding so what does return mean

Comment: your good, return is a keyword in functions to 1. end the function and 2. "return" a variable in the scope the function was called in, so if the function ends with "return starterchoice1,starterchoice2,starterchoice3" then you can now use those variables outside the function (not necessarily globally) by saying "starterchoice1,starterchoice2,starterchoice3 = myfunc()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you return the values from the first function directly into the second, it would look similar to this

```
def pick(poke_list):
  # Do things
  return starterchoice1, starterchoice2, starterchoice3


def send(starterchoice1, starterchoice2, starterchoice3):
  print(f'Your Starters are... {starterchoice1}, {starterchoice2} and {starterchoice3}. type .pick_The pokemons name to pick')
  return value

pick1, pick2, pick3 = pick(poke_list)
value = send(pick1, pick2, pick3)
```

Comment: question asker wanted to know what return does, this is a good example of how to use it, I do want to know what "value" is in send() though

Comment: It wouldn't let me use the variable in the second function

Comment: I typed return starterchoice1, starterchoice2, starterchoice3 and it didn't show in the function below it

Comment: can you share your code with us? need a bit more context to see what's happening

Comment: so here is what's going on

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqfNt.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg6iU.png

Comment: `await ctx.send (f'Your starters are {starterchoice1}, {starterchoice2} and {starterchoice3}')
    return starterchoice1, starterchoice3, starterchoice2`

Comment: `@bot.command()
async def pick_(ctx, *, var):
    if var == starter1:
        await ctx.send(f'added {starter1} to bank. Type .bank to veiw your pokemon')
    if var == starter2:
        await ctx.send(f'added {starter2} to bank. Type .bank to veiw your pokemon')
    if var == starter3:
        await ctx.send(f'added {starter3} to bank. Type .bank to veiw your pokemon')
    if not var == starter1 or starter2 or starter3:
        await ctx.send(f'{var} is not recognized as a pokemon right now')`

Comment: So, I couldn't get anything to help so I just changed my idea, but you guys can still answer it for the people that look on the question.

Answer (score -1):

If the two commands are in the same class as where you're instanciating those variables you can use *self* to refer to the variable.

[Why do I need to use "self" to reference the class variable in a class method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65095686/why-do-i-need-to-use-self-to-reference-the-class-variable-in-a-class-method)

So if you had

```
Class PokemonSelection():
    starterchoice1 = "Squirtle"
    starterchoice2 = "Treecko"
    starterchoice3 = "Rowlet"
def print_start_choices(self):
    print(f'Your Starters are... {self.starterchoice1}, {self.starterchoice2} and {self.starterchoice3}')
```

Comment: you need to do self.starterchoice1, preferably in a __init__ method

Comment: How can I use this in another function

Comment: this solution uses objects, which is not so beginner friendly and personally think unnecessary for what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).